# Specialize class for couple of possible arguments(typenames)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template class, the only template parameter is typename.

```
template<typename T>
class Reader{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to specialize it for every integer type, something like:

```
template<typename T - integral>
class Reader{
    //another code
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you add silent (defaulted) template parameters to `Reader`?

Comment: @Grizzly: no, it isn't good idea for me

Comment: In that case I think you are out of luck without explicitely specializing each type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dummy `std::true_type` parameter

```
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>
class Reader {

};

template<typename T>
class Reader<T, std::integral_constant<bool, 
                  std::is_integral<T>::value> > {
  // ...
};
```

Incidentally you will see this pattern used with `void` instead of `true_type`, with the specializations often using `enable_if` and more complicated (and SFINAE involving) conditions.

Comment: can you please give example with `enable_if`? You example works fine, I was tried something with `enable_if` but I get compile error #include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename = void>
class Name;

template<typename T>
class Name<T, std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type>
{
};
int main(){
Name<int> name;
}

Comment: An alternative is to use `typename std::is_integral<T>::type` as the second parameter to match.

Comment: @RiaD You need to put `typename` before `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @Luc Danton, can you please also explain why it's not working with just bool = true and  std::is_integral<T>::value

Comment: @RiaD I think the restriction is here to make matching specialization (the process at work here) more tractable. Matching `template<int I> struct foo<I, 2*I> {}` is given as an example -- it could get very hard to solve if things of that sort were allowed.

Comment: @RiaD see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978617/why-is-it-disallowed-for-partial-specialization-in-a-non-type-argument-to-use-ne . the committee couldn't explain it technically, so it seems the reason is historical.

Comment: @LucDanton thanks for the `::type` hint. I used to say `::integral_constant` which fails for GCC < 4.5, but didn't know about   `::type` :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just an extra defaulted boolean parameter:

```
template<typename T, bool IsIntegral = std::is_integral<T>::value>
class Reader{ // primary template, used for non-integrals
    ...
}

template<typename T>
class Reader<T, true> { // specialization for integral types
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add, that I know about this solution. But I want to be able to add new groups of specialization(i.e floats, strings(wstring, string, char*), and so on) without modification of old code.

Comment: You mean you can't change the `Reader` primary template? If so, you're out of luck.

Comment: It may still be interesting to showcase the usual solution (primary template matching anything, specializations that are partitioned across traits).

Answer (score 3):

In similar situations I have used the brute force approach of specializing the class template for all special types. I realize that these are quite a few and that it can become quickly rather painful. However, factoring the interesting members into a base class shared by all specializations works reasonably well. In the cases where I used this approach I typically only had static members in the class, i.e., the fact that constructors are not inherited wasn't a problem (C++ 2011 support a syntax to also inherit constructors but the while point is to keep the notation down):

```
template <typename T> class Reader { ... };

template <typename T> class IntReader { /* special version for integers */ };
// to bool or not bool?
template <> class Reader<wchar_t>: public IntReader<wchar_t> {};
template <> class Reader<char>: public IntReader<char> {};
template <> class Reader<char16_t>: public IntReader<char16_t> {};
template <> class Reader<char32_t>: public IntReader<char32_t> {};
template <> class Reader<signed char>: public IntReader<signed char> {};
template <> class Reader<signed short>: public IntReader<signed short> {};
template <> class Reader<signed int>: public IntReader<signed int> {};
template <> class Reader<signed long>: public IntReader<signed long> {};
template <> class Reader<signed long long>: public IntReader<signed long long> {};
template <> class Reader<unsigned char>: public IntReader<unsigned char> {};
template <> class Reader<unsigned short>: public IntReader<unsigned short> {};
template <> class Reader<unsigned int>: public IntReader<unsigned int> {};
template <> class Reader<unsigned long>: public IntReader<unsigned long> {};
template <> class Reader<unsigned long long>: public IntReader<unsigned long long> {};
```

Admittedly, we have too many integer types! Having **six** different character types is kind of ridiculous.

Comment: It will be a nightmare to add `const` and `volatile` to this :)

Comment: Nope, not really: you can provide the generic specializations and have them delegate to the version without cv-qualifiers.